# UITextField display issue in TableView cell

Tags: ios, xcode, uitextfield, tableview, cell

I created at least 10 cells with each UITextField on it, for registration page. When I insert  the words on the textfield in the first cell, and when I scrolled the tableView, the textfield which is in another cell show up the word that I just typed.

Below is my code. The textField data which I input is looping, which is caused by dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier... How can I solve this problem? Thank you very much.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RCell";
RegisterCell *cell = (RegisterCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    
if (cell == nil)
    cell = [[[RegisterCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 44) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];


if(indexPath.section == 0){
    NSDictionary *rowData = [self.regisLabel objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *mainLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [rowData objectForKey:@"regisLbl"]];
    cell.registerLabel.text = mainLabel;

    UITextField *valTxtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 5, 180, 30)];
    valTxtField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-CondensedExtraBold" size:18.0];
    valTxtField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    valTxtField.delegate = self;
    valTxtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    valTxtField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    valTxtField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;

    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        valTxtField.text = @"";
        emailTxtFld = valTxtField; //emailTxtFld is global variable
    }
    if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        valTxtField.text = @"";
        reEmailTxtFld = valTxtField; //reEmailTxtFld is global variable
    }

    [cell.contentView addSubview:valTxtField];
    [valTxtField release];
}    
else if(indexPath.section == 1){
    NSDictionary *rowData = [self.regisLabel objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]+10]; 
    NSString *mainLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [rowData objectForKey:@"regisLbl"]];
    cell.registerLabel.text = mainLabel;
    cell.registerTextField.enabled = NO;
}
else if(indexPath.section == 2){
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        NSDictionary *rowData = [self.regisLabel objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]+11];
        NSString *mainLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [rowData objectForKey:@"regisLbl"]];
        cell.registerLabel.text = mainLabel;
        cell.registerTextField.enabled = NO;
    }
}


return cell;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

An easy way is to just remove all subviews from the cells contentView before you add subviews, example:

```
for (UIView *subview in [cell.contentView subviews])
    [subview removeFromSuperview];
```

A more efficient way would be to do all the creation of cells inside the if (cell == nil) statement, but that depends on how many cells you have in the table.

Answer (score 0):

The right implementation is to move the creation of any view whithin if (cell == nil)
Like so:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"RCell";
RegisterCell *cell = (RegisterCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];    

UITextField *valTxtField;
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[[RegisterCell alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 280, 44) reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];

if(indexPath.section == 0){
    valTxtField = [[UITextField alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(120, 5, 180, 30)];
    valTxtField.font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Futura-CondensedExtraBold" size:18.0];
    valTxtField.contentVerticalAlignment = UIControlContentVerticalAlignmentCenter;
    valTxtField.delegate = self;
    valTxtField.returnKeyType = UIReturnKeyDone;
    valTxtField.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionTypeNo;
    valTxtField.autocapitalizationType = UITextAutocapitalizationTypeNone;
    valTxtField.tag = 100;

    [cell.contentView addSubview:valTxtField];
    [valTxtField release];
}
}

valTxtField = (UITextField *)[cell.contentView viewWithTag:100];


if(indexPath.section == 0){
    NSDictionary *rowData = [self.regisLabel objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];
    NSString *mainLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [rowData objectForKey:@"regisLbl"]];
    cell.registerLabel.text = mainLabel;

    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        valTxtField.text = @"";
        emailTxtFld = valTxtField; //emailTxtFld is global variable
    }
    if(indexPath.row == 1)
    {
        valTxtField.text = @"";
        reEmailTxtFld = valTxtField; //reEmailTxtFld is global variable
    }
}    
else if(indexPath.section == 1){
    NSDictionary *rowData = [self.regisLabel objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]+10]; 
    NSString *mainLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [rowData objectForKey:@"regisLbl"]];
    cell.registerLabel.text = mainLabel;
    cell.registerTextField.enabled = NO;
}
else if(indexPath.section == 2){
    if(indexPath.row == 0){
        NSDictionary *rowData = [self.regisLabel objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]+11];
        NSString *mainLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [rowData objectForKey:@"regisLbl"]];
        cell.registerLabel.text = mainLabel;
        cell.registerTextField.enabled = NO;
    }
}


return cell;
```